# setColor on void Paint()

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I have a function to draw on JPanelu, but does not change my color. always displays the white squares . Method set.Color doesn't work.

```
  public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            draw();
        }

public void draw(){
    Graphics g = map.getGraphics();
    int xx = map.getSize().width;
    int yy = map.getSize().height;

    for(int i = 0; i < (first+second); i++){    
        if(i < first){
            g.setColor( Color.red );
            g.clearRect( (3*x+1)*(xx/x/3),  (3*y+1)*(yy/y/3),(xx/x/3) , (yy/y/3) );
        }else{
            g.setColor(Color.black );
            int j = i - first;
            g.clearRect( (3*x+1)*(xx/x/3),  (3*y+1)*(yy/y/3),(xx/x/3) , (yy/y/3) );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [clearRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) which is effectively deleting that portion of the panel, and replaces it with the background color. Use the corresponding [drawRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)-method instead, which will employ the foreground color which you are correctly setting via [setColor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29).